# If $\det(A)\det(B) \ne 0$, are $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is it right to assume such that:

By proof of theorem,
\begin{align*}
\det(A)\det(B) &= \det(E_1E_2\dots E_k)\det(B)\\
               &= \det(E_1E_2\dots E_kB)\\
               &= \det(AB)\\
\end{align*}

Since both $A$ and $B$ are invertible and $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$ both does not equal zero, one of them is a row echelon form of the other? For example,

A = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  0&3&3\\
  -4&4&-1\\
  4&2&5
\end{array}
\right] $$

B = $$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  4&2&5\\
  0&6&4\\
0&0&1
\end{array}
\right] $$

$B$ is a row echelon form of $A$, hence $B$ and $A$ are row equivalent since $\det(A)\det(B) \ne 0$

Is there a way to explain this concept in terms of elementary matrices?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are both square matrices and $\det(AB)\neq 0$ this implies that both $A$ and $B$ are invertible and therefore are both row equivalent to the identity matrix (*and thus to eachother*).  It does not imply anything about whether either is in row echelon form.